# What do you call a number that is not a factor of another?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, definition, factoring

If $2$ is a factor of $4$, what would $3$ be? A non-factor? Anti-factor?

I've tried searching for this online but I couldn't find an answer for some odd reason. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong spots.

Comment: I have heard mainly "non-factor" or "non-divisor" personally

Comment: Non-factor sounds fine.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nondivisor

Comment: In the project I'm working on, I've opted to use "non-factor". However, it doesn't seem to be too official as there aren't any references to the use of this term online.

Comment: I guess nondivisor works as well

Comment: "$3$ is *not a factor* of $4$" written with symbols as $3\nmid 4$.  I don't see why there explicitly needs to be a shortening of the phrase "*is not a factor*" into something like "*is a non-factor.*"  Writing it as "*is not a factor*" is already short and perfectly understandable.

Comment: Maybe it is used in something like "There are an odd number of positive non-factors for the number 3 up to 3."